# Workflow for XCode & Git sharing code?

Tags: xcode, git, xib, merge-conflict-resolution

What is the best practice / process for sharing code using git between developers working on an iPhone application.

Everytime I follow the normal git-fetch, git-rebase origin/master, method from the command line I get conflicts in the .xcodeproj, .xib, and Storyboard files.

The .xib isn't so bad because its ussually easy to fix, however the .xcodeproj consistently corrupts and I haven't found an easy way to consistently fix it.

What's the best workflow to share project files and resolve conflicts with git?

Answer (score 1):

Conflicts in project files are always a pain. The same thing happens in .NET development and Visual Studio. The best way to handle this is to not have too many changes to merge at once. You do this by merging in each other's changes on an integration branch. To keep branches clean, you don't merge that branch or the other person's back to yours. You rely on rerere to remember all your conflicts along the way. This is the workflow I use:

http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

If you really get stuck, you would likely look at what changes were done on the other side (what you're merging in), checkout your version of the project file, manually do what the other branch did to the project file, and then use that as the solution to the conflict.

The issue is that the IDE is doing it's own thing when you update your project. So sometimes, you need to manually use the IDE to simulate adding all the stuff yourself and using that file as the conflict resolution.

This is the dark side of using heavy IDEs for development.